# K&R 4.2 atof function

Tags: c

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXLINE 1000

double atof(char []);
int getline(char in[], int maxline);

main()
   {
     char input[MAXLINE];
     int n;
     double x;

     while ((n = getline(input, MAXLINE)) > 0)
        printf("%s\n", input);
     x = atof(input);
     printf("%lf\n", x);
     system("PAUSE");
    }

 int getline(char in[], int maxline)
    {
      int c, i;
      i = 0;
      while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')
         in[i++] = c;
      if (c == '\n')
        in[i++] = c;
      in[i] = '\0';
      return i - 1;
     }

    /*atof convert string to double*/

    double atof(char s[])
     {
        double val, power;
        int i, sign;

        for (i = 0; isspace(s[i]);++i)
           ;
        sign = (s[i] == '-') ? -1 : 1;
        if (s[i] == '+' || s[i] == '-')
           ++i;
        for (val = 0.0; isdigit(s[i]); i++)
           val = 10.0*val + (s[i] - '0');          
        if (s[i] == '.')
           ++i;
        for (power = 1.0; isdigit(s[i]); i++)
         {
           val = 10.0*val + (s[i] - '0');
           power *= 10.0;
         }
         return sign * val / power;
       }
```

atof function is exactly same as the sample code in page 71.
return value of atof is like 100.000 or something. out of order..
getline works fine as far as I know. not my first time to type getline..
there is something wrong with atof receiving the char array I think.
what am I doing wrong?
please help!

Comment: Please create [mcve]. If `getline` function is not relevant to your question, then remove that and pass fixed string literal to your `atof` function. Currently we don't know what your input and expected output is.

Comment: Note that `getline()` is the name of a [POSIX-standard function](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getdelim.html).  If you were to compile your code on a POSIX-compliant system, you'd likely see compiler warnings, and depending on your code you might get unexpected failures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is wrong:

You probably want this:

```
  while ((n = getline(input, MAXLINE)) > 0)
  {
    printf("%s\n", input);
    x = atof(input);
    printf("%lf\n", x);
  }
```

Comment: That was such a simple and elementary mistake.Thank you very much! Stackoverflow FTW!!!

Comment: @SungJuneKye you're welcome to upvote/accept this answer.

Comment: Unfortunately my rep is under 15 so it won't change public displayed score. :(

Comment: @SungJuneKye to accept an answer is mainly a way to mark the question closed. You cannot accept an answer with your score ?

Comment: I just got it. sorry I am too new. marked the answer now.